# How can I force a command to execute before an application starts running

Tags: scripts, startup

I want to perform certain actions via a bash script before opening any application eg. firefox/ deluge/ VLC via GUI or CLI. The script should be executed only for certain applications and not for all. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take advantage of the fact that the path is searched in order for applications.

```
roadmr@blackdog:~$ which firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
roadmr@blackdog:~$ echo $PATH
/home/roadmr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

So when you try to run "firefox" it will be searched for in those directories, it's eventually found in `/usr/bin` and executed.

But if you place a wrapper named `firefox` in e.g. `/usr/local/bin`, which does the pre-run actions you require and ends up calling `/usr/bin/firefox` (absolute path here, or you'll end up in a loop) then this wrapper will be used whenever someone runs just "firefox" (and note that the `.Desktop` launcher also specifies just "firefox", a relative name which will still search in the `PATH`). This is because `/usr/local/bin/firefox` comes before `/usr/bin/firefox` in path search order.

Comment: Only downside might be that the right-click `open with` option might (probably) be broken, since the wrapper will probably not be able to handle it. It usually *does* brake when you run an application via a detour in the `.desktop` file.

Comment: If the wrapper passes the command-line parameters verbatim to the wrapped application it should be OK. For instance, if the wrapper to firefox does: `/usr/bin/firefox $@` it should just pass whatever it was invoked with, so the actual firefox binary will see the parameters as sent.

Comment: Thanks! That is new to me, good information. Very smart trick by the way.  +1

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Will this work if I say, open a magnet link from browser which then opens deluge?